# How to make a simple timerAnimation in android studio?

Tags: android, timer

I searched a lot for how to make simple TimerAnimator like Value animator
can anyone tell me how to do it very simply

this is the one for value animator

```
ValueAnimator timeAnimator=ValueAnimator.ofInt(1,10);
    timeAnimator.addUpdateListener(new ValueAnimator.AnimatorUpdateListener() {
        @Override
        public void onAnimationUpdate(ValueAnimator animation) {
            int currentvalue= (int) animation.getAnimatedValue();
            tttt.setText(String.valueOf(currentvalue));


        }
    });
    timeAnimator.setDuration(20000);
    timeAnimator.start();
```

Comment: What is `TimerAnimation`? Can you provide a resource ?

Comment: thats why i didnt get any resource , it is a type of value animator , ,https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jwdTNaddHHs see this link

Comment: I think its `TimeAnimator` you are looking for [Here is a resource you can use](https://medium.com/@patrick_iv/continuous-animation-using-timeanimator-5b8a903603fb). If its the same thing you need or you search yourself .

Comment: check : https://github.com/IvanRF/CountDownAnimation